# Visual Studio - Imread system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I have a huge problem with reading my images using OpenCV for Visual Studio 2017

[image]

My program is not able to find my image while it does exist (I checked it multiple times it does exist on my E:/ drive). I've put the image on a relative path, an absolute path but whatever I try it doesn't seem to matter it is still not able to find the image. I've also put the image in the same folder as the .exe program and added it as a resource etc.

```
 Mat img = imread("E:\\test.jpg", 0);
 Mat img = imread("E:/test.jpg", 0);
 Mat img = imread("E:\test.jpg", 0);
 Mat img = imread("test.jpg", 0);
```

All of the above examples returned the error in the image provided.

These are my imports:

```
  #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
  #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
  #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
  #include <iostream>
  #include <math.h>
```

I've tried some potential fixes however they did not work at all. I assume that my problem is related to Visual studio and not to OpenCV (My OpenCV is correctly installed). Are my settings in my project settings wrong? Or is my problem related to something different?

Build error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Alphatree, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Mat __cdecl cv::imread(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (?imread@cv@@YA?AVMat@1@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z) referenced in function main
1>E:\In-company research project\In-company-research\ConsoleApplication4\Alphatree.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication4.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Visual Studio can't find your program, this has nothing to with your image. Did it even compile successfully?

Comment: Yes it does compile successful, however the build fails. Whenever I remove the Imread the program works fine and it compiles/builds/runs successful

Comment: What's the build error?

Comment: I've added the build error to the main text

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue, the problem was that I didn't include every single library provided by OpenCV instead I only used 3. Now that I included every single library the program works, be aware that these are the debug libraries!

```
opencv_calib3d411d.lib
opencv_core411d.lib
opencv_dnn411d.lib
opencv_features2d411d.lib
opencv_flann411d.lib
opencv_gapi411d.lib
opencv_highgui411d.lib
opencv_imgcodecs411d.lib
opencv_imgproc411d.lib
opencv_ml411d.lib
opencv_objdetect411d.lib
opencv_photo411d.lib
opencv_stitching411d.lib
opencv_video411d.lib
opencv_videoio411d.lib
```

Comment: Note that you only need the opencv_highgui411d.lib, opencv_videoio411d.lib, opencv_imgcodecs411d.lib to fix your error.